# Weird black line on iPhone Safari in a Bootstrap site

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'm working on a project based on Bootstrap and I get a weird black line (no borders and even no div could have this black line). BUG?

[image: iphone safari screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: the black line is not on the computer screen!!

Comment: Have you checked the `background image`?